# MySql: How to delete the delay between SELECT and UPDATE

Tags: mysql

I have a simple set up for assigning opponents in a game. 
Basically if the matchID is zero(value comes from elsewhere), a new match needs to be created, and it will perform a mysql select on the last matchID record to ascertain if there is someone waiting for a match or not.

To see if a player is waiting we can see if the teamB space is Zero (not taken). If however teamB has a value then no one is waiting and a new match must be created with this player as a 'team A'.

The code is as follows:

```
    if ($matchID == 0)
{
  $teamBquery = $conn ->query("SELECT matchID,teamBID,teamAID FROM challengeMatches ORDER BY matchID DESC LIMIT 1 ");
$teamBarray = $teamBquery->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$teamBID=$teamBarray[teamBID];
$matchID=$teamBarray[matchID];
$teamAID=$teamBarray[teamAID];
    if ($teamBID == 0){
        $newChallenge = $conn ->query ("UPDATE challengeMatches SET managerBID='$managerID', teamBID='$teamID',matchStatus=1 WHERE matchID='$matchID'");

    }else{
       $filler = 0;
        $matchID = $matchID+1;
        $newChallenge = $conn ->query ("INSERT INTO challengeMatches (matchID,managerAID,managerBID,matchStatus,teamAID,teamBID) VALUES ('','$managerID','$filler','$filler','$teamID','$filler')");

    }
}
```

My concern as someone pretty inexperienced is that as far as I can see there will be a delay between selecting the info and updating the info and so technically two mysql selects might return the same matchID to be used. And then even using the matchID+1 as variable is risky because it could be out of sync with the auto-increment matchID that is created in the database.

Are my fears founded or is the code so fast that the probability is not worth worrying about?

If i should be worried what can I do?

Comment: The time taken for execution depends primarily on your system hardwares. Normally, it takes ~1 microsecond or less to execute an entire file.

Comment: @Dream so I shouldn't be worried? I've read a little bit this morning, with the likes of locking/innodb but seems poss overkill.

Comment: If you do want to have better results, let MySQL do all the work for you. Use transactions.

Comment: @dream, ok on the case thanks +1

Answer (score 1):

You firstly need to identify if you really need a solution to overcome this, the time gap should be so small unless you run a massive site the likelihood of selecting two matchId's is remote.

However there are really three area's you can look to improve this:

1. Locking - look at `SELECT .. FOR UPDATE` or `SELECT ... LOCK IN SHARE MODE`
2. Transactions
3. Refactor the database to actually update with a limit first and then select the updated range

Comment: Thanks +1. I hadn't realised that this question would solicit 'value judgments' (because the parsers are so fast) I presumed I had oversimplified the code and was creating a problem for later.

Comment: @Gamemorize there is nothing wrong with analysising what might happen when you're writing code - but sometimes its too easy to over optiomise which can cause more performance problems in the long run.  A good strategery is to code carefully, profile your query's and then address issues that really need your attention.